# class cast exception when data binding with list

Tags: grails, data-binding

The domain looks like

```
class EventDonation implements Serializable{

    String title
    String body
    Integer customDonationMin
    Integer customDonationMax   

    EntityStatus status

    List denominations

    static hasMany = [denominations: Integer]


}
```

Please note that the denominations is a list of Integers. Now during binding

```
List<String> whiteList = ['title', 'body', 'customDonationMin', 'customDonationMax', 'denominations']
bindData(don, params, ['include': whiteList])


if(params.status){
    don.status = EntityStatus.ACTIVE            
}
else{           
    don.status = EntityStatus.INACTIVE          
}


don.validate()

if(don.hasErrors()){

    render(view: "editdonation", model: [id:id, donation:don])
    return

}
```

The following error is displayed

```
Message: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

In the view page there are 4 textboxes for entering denominations. I was thinking that the strings i.e '10', '20', '30', '40' will automatically be converted to integers during binding. I think the error is associated with binding this list. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Interesting thing is when i change the type of the list to String as follows:

```
class EventDonation implements Serializable{

    String title
    String body
    Integer customDonationMin
    Integer customDonationMax   

    EntityStatus status

    List denominations

    static hasMany = [denominations: String]

}
```

The following binding works fine i.e no error is thrown.

```
List<String> whiteList = ['title', 'body', 'customDonationMin', 'customDonationMax', 'denominations']
bindData(don, params, ['include': whiteList])


if(params.status){
    don.status = EntityStatus.ACTIVE            
}
else{           
    don.status = EntityStatus.INACTIVE          
}


don.validate()

if(don.hasErrors()){

    render(view: "editdonation", model: [id:id, donation:don])
    return

}
```

So, i am confident that the type Integer for the list is the source of the problem. Since denominations are integers i cannot think of any other type. I appreciate any help on this. Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you remove `List denominations` from your domain classs? `hasMany` adds this property anyway.

Comment: can you add the params map which you are getting over here ?

Comment: @RahulBGangwar In the view page, i put 4 integers for denominations namely 4, 6, 7, 9 and printed the params map as follows: [denominations[2]:7, denominations[1]:6, denominations[0]:4, body:Donation Body, title:Donation Title, customDonationMax:100, create:Submit, denominations[3]:9, _status:, customDonationMin:1, id:1, action:updatedonation, controller:donation]

Comment: the puzzling thing is that the error occurs only when binding the to denominations list so i am positive that the problem is associated with the way i am binding to the denominations list. In the view, i have named the 4 textboxes denominations[0], denominations[1], denominations[2], denominations[3]. I hope the problem isn't here.